# Posting an from React not reaching AWS, despite a response 200 and testing it out with Bruno(alternative Postman) works (i.e. backend is fine)

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, mern

I am trying to post images from a react component:

```
     <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} method="post">
          <input
            type="file"
            accept="image/*"
            onChange={onImageChange}
            name="image"
            multiple
          />
          <button type="submit">Upload</button>
          <button onClick={fetchImages}>Fetch</button>
        </form>
```

but despite having a http response 200 `POST /api/image/upload 200 3.472 ms - 77,` the images are not uploading to AWS. I have done my troubleshooting, but yet to see how I can fix it:

I have been following this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k9-3ZLvhL9Q&t=1228s), and with this as my multer code:

```
const uploadWithMulter = () =>
  multer({
    storage: multerS3({
      s3: s3,
      bucket: BUCKET_NAME,
      metadata: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, { fieldname: file.fieldname });
      },
      key: function (req, file, cb) {
        cb(null, file.originalname);
      },
    }),
  }).array("s3Images", 2);

const uploadToAws = (req, res) => {
  const upload = uploadWithMulter();
  // log("req %o", req);
  upload(req, res, (error) => {
    if (error) {
      res.json({ error, msg: "Error occurred while uploading images." });
      return;
    }
    res.json({ msg: "Files uploaded successfully.", files: req.files });
  });
};
```

I actually managed to get my backend working by testing my api/routes on Bruno(alt to Postman).

This is the response I receive:

```
{
  "msg": "Files uploaded successfully.",
  "files": []
}
```

Having seemingly successfully(?) set up my backend, I then proceed to debug from the frontend:

Log when a file from input is selected shows the selected file:

```
[Console.log of onImageChange](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HF8r.png)
```

Log from my handleSubmit:

```
  for (const entry of formData.entries()) {
      const [key, value] = entry;
      console.log(`${key}:`, value);
    }
```

also logs my input [Console.log of formData](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4Rr1.png).

With all these troubleshooting, I get a response 200, but also the error message that I have set:

```
  upload(req, res, (error) => {
    if (error) {
      res.json({ error, msg: "Error occurred while uploading images." });
      return;
    }
```

What exactly am I missing or how can I troubleshoot further?